# Making a simplified angular material accordion, but Output event is not caught

Tags: angular, angular-material, eventemitter

I am trying to simplify the angular material accordion by making my own version which is trying to simplify it a bit.
I have a **stepper component**:

```
<mat-accordion>
    <ng-content>
    </ng-content>
</mat-accordion>
```

This is very simple and has these methods:

```
import {
  Component,
  AfterViewInit,
  QueryList,
  ContentChildren,
  OnDestroy,
  Input
} from "@angular/core";
import { StepComponent } from "./step.component";
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";

@Component({
  selector: "app-stepper",
  templateUrl: "./stepper.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./stepper.component.scss"]
})
export class StepperComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @Input() closeOthers: boolean = true;
  @ContentChildren(StepComponent) children: QueryList<any>;

  step = 0;
  private subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.children.forEach((child: StepComponent, i: number) => {
      this.subscriptions.add(
        child.animate.subscribe(() => {
          this.setStep(i);
        })
      );
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.subscriptions.unsubscribe();
  }

  setStep(index: number) {
    this.step = index;
    console.log(this.step);
  }

  nextStep() {
    this.step++;
    console.log(this.step);
  }

  prevStep() {
    this.step--;
    console.log(this.step);
  }
}
```

Please note the `children` subscriptions.

Then I created a **step component**

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded"
    (click)="animateMe()">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            {{name}}
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
    <div>
        <ng-content>
        </ng-content>
    </div>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

This is where I want to hide the complexity of the accordion steps. Currently it is basic, but bear with me.
Then my code looks like this:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-step",
  templateUrl: "./step.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./step.component.scss"]
})
export class StepComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name: string;
  @Input() expanded: boolean;
  @Output() animate: EventEmitter<void> = new EventEmitter<void>();

  constructor() {}

  ngOnInit() {}

  animateMe() {
    console.log("clicked");
    this.animate.emit();
  }
}
```

Note the `Output` event.
So, in my component I now have this:

```
<app-stepper #stepper>
    <app-step name="Hall"
        *ngIf="hall"
        [expanded]="stepper.step === 0">


        <!-- emitted for brevity -->

        <button mat-raised-button
            type="button"
            color="primary"
            (click)="stepper.nextStep()">Next</button>
    </app-step>
    <app-step name="Video"
        [expanded]="stepper.step === 1">

        <!-- emitted for brevity -->

        </form>
    </app-step>
</app-stepper>
```

When I press the button for the next step, it does indeed expand that "step". But if I click any of the headers, although I do see a console log (so the event emitter is actually emitting) the subscription is not caught and so the "step" is not reset.

Does anyone know why my code:

```
this.children.forEach((child: StepComponent, i: number) => {
  this.subscriptions.add(
    child.animate.subscribe(() => {
      this.setStep(i);
    })
  );
});
```

Is not getting caught?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-za4qtb) as this seemed like an interesting problem.

If I'm understanding the problem correctly, I think it's actually a #simple fix.

I've moved the click event from the `mat-expansion-panel` in the step component to `mat-expansion-header`.

```
<mat-expansion-panel [expanded]="expanded">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header (click)="animateMe()">
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

As you say, the subscription is firing, but then the click handler was overwriting the call to `nextStep`, causing it to reset.

I assume I've misunderstood the problem based on the simplicity of this?

Comment: I will mark this as the answer, the actual issue was because on my first step I have the `*ngIf="hall"` and because of that, it wasn't registering that there are actually 2 steps. But you are right, the click event should be on the header, not that overall panel

Comment: Classic simple oversights